# Threejs WebXR controller detect hand

Tags: three.js, webxr

First of all, I'm a complete noob in three.js and currently struggled with detecting the hand of the controller. I want to achieve something like that:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  const controller = renderer.xr.getController(i);
  console.debug(controller.hand); // 'left', 'right' ??
  scene.add(controller);
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Never used XR before, but maybe you could [browse through the webxr examples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=webxr#webxr_vr_ballshooter) and see if any one of them differentiate between left or right hand? You can see the source code by clicking on the `< >` button on the bottom-right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `XRInputSource.handedness`. From the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webxr/#ref-for-enumdef-xrhandedness):

> The handedness attribute describes which hand the XR input source is associated with, if any.

In `three.js`, input sources are mapped to controllers. Meaning you can evaluate the handedness like so:

```js
controller.addEventListener( 'connected', ( event ) => {

    console.log( event.data.handedness );

} );
```

`three.js r116`